# How to have real borders around windows in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

Is there a way to have the old-style-not-modern-flat-style real borders around windows in Windows 10?

I am thinking about real frames that clearly cut off the content of the border. The default setting makes working in some windows nightmarish (below are two putty windows that overlap and I never know where I am)

[image]

Comment: <rant>Yes, it really is one of the worst user interfaces ever devised, isn't it?</rant>  ;)

Comment: You could try going to settings > personalization > colors > enable Title bars and window borders

Comment: @lost_admin I went there but there are no borders that appear (just some weird coloring of bars)

Comment: See answers by Pejole2165 and Marctraider>>>>https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/136111-any-way-get-active-window-borders-back.html

Comment: @Moab: thanks, I tried that before asking here (as well as the other program mentioned by someone else) but I just got a translucent bar. I will try to get more out of this program then, but I was hoping for some built-in solution (even if it means changing some registry, that part is fine)

Comment: @WoJ yeah, the elegant look of windows is tricky... maybe control panel > system and security > system > advanced system settings > settings > visual effects > and then turn on show shadows under windows option.

Comment: @WoJ if you feel comfortable with registry editing, this post has some information, however the results dont seem to be consistent. >>> https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/windows-10-how-to-get-rid-of-thick-colored-borders/a53e9a03-d2af-4e43-a30a-ba17f64a7e41